# Data from API return null how to exclude it

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter : I am using youtube API and fetching data from it, sometimes the videos has no tags so it returns null.
My code is

If my code not understandable, I can attach full code.

```
 tags: List<String>.from(json["tags"]!.map((x) => x)),
```

is there anyway to exclude the conversion operation if json["tags"] have null values..

Also tried below but not working.

```
   tags: null == json["tags"] ? null : List<String>.from(json["tags"]!.map((x) => x)),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List.from((json["tags"] ?? [])!.map((x) => x)),
```

Use the ?? operator to check if tags is null, else use an empty list.